# disable touch events for RecyclerView inside NestedScrollV

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a layout like below:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/devito" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/rating"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Danny DeVitto"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Info"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/someList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/anotherList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Where idea is toolbar is collapsing when scrolled up (down?). But there is a problem with where touch event is occurred. If scroll initiated on any element except RecyclerView, everything works like a charm. But if scroll touch is initiated on recyclerview, NestedScrollView starts scrolling without toolbar collapse or expand. RecyclerViews use custom layout manager, which wraps its content (each RecyclerView has few items). So here is a question. How to tell RecyclerView to not to interfere with NestedScrollView's collapsing/expanding behavior?

Comment: If I recall... you may have to actually create your own custom recyclerview adapter and have it stop detecting the scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem but with **NestedScrollView** i used

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

and the problem was gone, please try to add this and tell me if it works

Good luck

Comment: I guess this might work, but I've gone other way around.. I replaced my recyclerview with needed number of textviews..)) I'm gonna check this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener()  {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return true; //Consume the touch event
        }
        ...
    });
```